# opening file directory by not using a string

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

Ok I may have the title wrong. But this is what I want to do. I know how to open file directories. What I was wander can I use

```
System.Diagnostic.Process.Start(@" ");
```

Now the empty quotes is my question. Instead of me manually imputing each application in code. Can is it possible that I can leave it blank.

I am using speech.synthesis and I was wanting to try to avoid if and else statements. However, if I add a new app to my desktop, I would have to update the program for the new app to be apart of the system.

My original way is like this

```
if (speech == "open notepad")
{
system.Diagnostic.Process.Start(@"notepad.exe);
}
else
{
if (speech == "open wordpad")
{
Sytem.Diagnostic.Process.Start(@"wordpad.exe);
}
```

So on and so on.. Is there a way to have an open "  "  that will automatically open the directory when called. So I do not have to keep doing program updates and releases..

This is done in winforms, and is for my own personal use.. The reason why I ask is, if I do release it to the public, then the programs I have listed, the user may or may not have my programs.

Comment: I know about the lower case letters in the script, my phone auto corrects. But you get the point

Comment: It's unclear what you are asking. What do you mean by *Is there a way to have an open " " that will automatically open the directory when called.* What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Can I call the program file in c:/ instead of doing the programs manually.

Comment: You can run a program by specifying the path t o it's executable. You also can open windows explorer. What is your requirement. Please clarify the question.

Comment: What do you not understand, you say I can open a program by the path... If you read the question you will see I am spread doing that.

Answer (score 0):

if you have the speech-to-text dictionary, why not store the user input into a string, then attempt to open a program with that string. Obviously you'll need to verify it's an installed program. I wish I could give you demo code, but I have no idea what StoT you're using.

Comment: I know how to open files using speech. The thing is on a small project I did which is a small customizable digital assistant. We found that since I am using win8.1 the programs I have are not on the machine being tested on. Which throws an error and craps out the program. I know if you use the speech recognition used by Microsoft going through the control panel, when you say start listening, you can say a program and it opens. I am using this as an example. So in this point of view, does Microsoft use String Variables?

Comment: I also know when you add a program to your desktop. It is also added into the list of programs, so you can say the new program and it opens.. So are they using something like this    System.Diagnostic.Process.Start(@"c:\ " + Settings.Default.User + " \Desktop " + StringVariable);

Comment: I just thought of something. What if I use a     {get, set}  to the programs directory, in a list

Comment: Ahh, so if I'm correct what you're asking is more along the lines of "How do you find what programs are installed on the PC"; as that seems to be the bulk of your issues at this point. Personally, I can't say I've ever done anything like this, but a bit of searching seems to imply you can pull that information from the registry programmatically.  Sorry I can't be of more help to you, and gl!